# Sending emails through SMTP client using current logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web site set up that has some forms authentication through LDAP. I'm sending an email when the currently logged in user clicks a button, however the email is being sent from my address, and not the user. This creates a bit of confusion.

What I want to do is send emails using the logged users account without having them enter their user information again.

I basically want to do this:

```
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress(User.GetIdentity);
    message.Subject = Subject;
    message.Body = body;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("address.qweqwe", 25);
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(User.Identity);
    client.Send(message);
```

Getting the users email isn't a big deal, I've already got methods for that, but I'm not sure how I should go about getting their credentials. They've already logged on to access the page, and I know they have an LDAP email.

Is there any way to do this without forcing the user to log in again just to send the email?

Comment: Can't you just store the userId in a session variable when the user types it in during logon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SMTP server requires Credentials, I can see 2 solutions.

1. Ask the user through the page from their Network Credential (username/password)
2. Setup an account that has right to relay on behalf of all users.  This would allow you to set a single account for the SMTP server.  Then, every time you send an email all you would do is change the MailMessage.From property.